# How do you convert indexed color image numpy array to RGB color-space?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I would like to convert indexed color image array to RGB color-space. I know I can achieve that if I have PIL read image like following.

```
with Image.open(png_image_path) as img:
    rgb_image = np.asarray(img.convert('RGB'))
```

I wanna do the same thing from numpy array rather than the image object read by PIL like following.

```
image = Image.fromarray(indexed_image).convert('RGB')
```

But it doesn't simply work the way I want. Any suggestion will be helpful to me! Thank you for taking your time.

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do this differently? That might help when figuring out a workaround.

Comment: I have labeled data for segmentation network which is indexed as class arg number. After I trained the neural network, it predicts the index number for each pixel. So now I wanna visualize the predicted pixel. That is why I wanted to convert the indexed color to RGB color-space.

Comment: @KousukeKuzuoka, did you figure out how to achieve this? 

I also have an image IMAGE_1 coming out of a NN which contains pixels numbered from 1 to 10 (since I have 10 classes) and I would like to use my own palette that looks like this `[[255 255 255 ], [168 10 25 ]...[222 10 45]]` and use it to convert the image IMAGE_1 to an RGB image with the colors I have in the palette.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```py
scr = numpy.frombuffer(screen_buffer, dtype=numpy.uint8)
pal = numpy.frombuffer(palette_buffer, dtype=numpy.uint8).reshape((256, 3))

# Convert indexed color to RGB
arr = pal[scr]

data = arr.astype(numpy.uint8).tobytes()
```